# Magento 2.2.2 multillanguage url rewrite

Tags: magento2, seo, product-urls

using Magento 2.2.2, I have a store with two views English and French,

I want to make urls looks like

domain.com/en/product1
domain.com/fr/category1

...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Admin -> Store -> All Stores`, make sure the store view codes are set as `English = en` and `French = fr`.

And in Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> URL Options -> `Add store code to URLs`